# Is this site just for books?

Tags: discussion, scope

Is this site just for books, or is it also for movies, TV shows, video games, etc.? For instance, I don't see a lot of questions about children's TV shows (many of which feature magic); so, I thought I'd ask.

I was reading through the help center, but I didn't find anything on that.

Comment: *Please* ask questions about children's TV shows.  Right now we've only got [Avatar](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/avatar-the-last-airbender) and a couple of other really popular ones.

Comment: It's interesting that you thought this site is only for books when [many have expressed the annoyance of HNQ](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6857/is-there-a-way-to-hide-the-hnq-list) every time a new movie (spoiler) come out :)

Answer (score 24, accepted):

**Science fiction and fantasy in all forms of media is welcome here.**

We have tags for [movie](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/movie), [tv](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/tv), and [video-games](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/video-games) as well as for [books](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/books), [novel](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/novel), and [short-stories](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/short-stories). (Inconsistent pluralisation, I know. Sorry.) And even beyond these tags, which are generally used only for ID questions or to distinguish between the same story in different media, a glance through our top tags and questions should confirm that we take questions about TV and films as well as books: [star-wars](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/star-wars), [star-trek](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/star-trek), [doctor-who](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/doctor-who), and [game-of-thrones](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/game-of-thrones) are all predominantly if not entirely for questions about screen stuff.

Answer (score 10):

@RandalThor is correct. In fact, my perception has been that book questions are in the minority here (but still on-topic).

Here are some other non-book tags to check out:

[marvel-cinematic-universe](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/marvel-cinematic-universe)
[dc-animated-universe](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/dc-animated-universe)
[x-men-cinematic-universe](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/x-men-cinematic-universe)
[transformers-live-action-series](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/transformers-live-action-series)
[power-rangers](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/power-rangers)
[deadpool-2016](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/deadpool-2016)
[stargate](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/stargate)
[sonic-the-hedgehog](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/sonic-the-hedgehog)
[the-terminator-series](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/the-terminator-series)
[pokemon](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pokemon)
[back-to-the-future](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/back-to-the-future)
[beetlejuice](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/beetlejuice)
[half-life](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/half-life)
[halo](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/halo)