# Ignored tag still shows up in HNQ?

Tags: bug, feature-request, tags

I recently added [harry-potter](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/harry-potter) and [fantastic-beasts](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/fantastic-beasts) to my ignored tags. I haven't seen the movie yet and I don't want to get any spoilers from question titles. While the questions successfully disappeared from my question feed on computer, I still see them on my phone in the `feed` screen.

Is there a way to prevent that?

[image: My ignored tags]
[image: My phone screen]

Comment: Ignored tags do show up on the HNQ. It's a [known bug/feature](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/224108/prevent-questions-with-movie-tv-shows-game-spoilers-from-appearing-in-the-hot-qu/305376#305376)

Comment: Yeah, [this is a well-known issue](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6857/is-there-a-way-to-hide-the-hnq-list), I'm afraid.

Comment: The linked question's idea of hiding questions with `spoilers` tag is a better idea than mine. Well there goes my first meta question

Comment: The app doesn't even hide the questions when you're in the specific site.